# Enable SpeechSynthesis API in the Web Browser on Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: kubuntu, firefox, chromium, text-to-speech, brave

Is there any web browser I can install in Kubuntu 20.04 that supports the web standards as it pertains to [Speech Synthesis](https://wicg.github.io/speech-api/)?

I've tried [Firefox](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1866880), [Chromium](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1792300), and Brave.

This web standard once worked fine in Ubuntu 16.04, but it has become a regression bug in the latest Kubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Is there anything I can do to enable this feature? I've been reporting this issue for over two years and it just remains as an open bug with no fixes in sight.

That's why I'm coming here: to search for a workaround that doesn't involve a Windows 10 virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Kubuntu 20.04 doesn't currently install `speech-dispatcher` by default like other desktops do.

Until they get that package into their default Kubuntu installation, this command will allow you to manually install speech-dispatcher:

```
sudo apt install speech-dispatcher
```

After installing this, restart Firefox, an go to a page that supports Speech Synthesis ([example](http://www.lonniebest.com/CardTrick/)).

If you can assist in getting this into the default install of Kubuntu, there is bug about this [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kubuntu-meta/+bug/1866880).

Comment: This only help with Firefox, but not Brave or Chromium, unfortunately.